# How to make this emeral shader look like this?

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency, glass

Is there anyone here who can show me how to make shading like this art?

[image]

https://www.instagram.com/p/CGryePsAuaz/ (high quality)

Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try something like this - you may need to play with the two different *Roughness* values depending on your lighting:

[image: Gem]

Speaking of lighting - I used a couple of "Tricks" to make the Gem look appropriate - below are my world settings and lighting setup - the *actively* selected light is below the gem, the rest are above - all default 1000w strength.

[image: GemLights]

Comment: That's an interesting world shader.  I'm going to add it to my collection.

Comment: That particular World Shader simply separates 2 Backgrounds - One providing only the image (or color), and the other providing only the lighting/reflections. In this case I "borrowed" the lighting and reflections from an HDRI image, but still kept the background roughly the same color as the OP's reference image.

Comment: all of my world shaders are very simple, they either produce no light, uniform light, or use the HDRI.  It's the way you mix the shaders that I hadn't thought to try.